# why <?php tag is closing on $user ->

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

As in title, in my html5 document, php script is ending too early, due to misreading -> as a closing tag. I have no idea why? I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver.

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
$user -> session_begin();
$auth -> acl($user = data);
$user -> setup();
?>
```

It's not just highlighting error, and removing spaces makes no difference. Changed session_begin() to session_start() still nothing. I can see lines

```
session_start(); $auth->acl($user = data); $user->setup(); ?>
```

on my website.

The problem was, my file was a .html file ;> Thanks for replies

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: `$user ->`? Can you post some more code then?

Comment: Is it maybe a Dreamweaver's highlight error?

Comment: Based on your title, `$user ->` should be `$user->`, without the space between $user an the hyphen. Otherwise, there's no way to determine what's going on without code. Is the script itself ending when you run it, or just the syntax highlighting in dreamweaver?

Comment: `->` is not a PHP closing tag. Could be mis-interpreted by a syntax highlighter bug.

Comment: No code, no party! Post some code, I'm not a wizard.

Comment: more code please, but maybe your server does not show php errors and $user->something fails.

Comment: I very very strongly suspect that is not what is happening, I suggest you put your code on http://pastebin.com/ and share the link with us.  Cheers :)

Comment: Has anyone suggested already that some code should be posted?

Comment: On a more serious note, does the PHP script *actually* end there when you view the page, or does Dreamweaver just *suggest* that it ends there?

Comment: Check the file you're `include`-ing, the problem could be in there too.

Comment: On a completely different note, `$auth->acl($user = data);` doesn't seem kosher to me. What is "data"?

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem, but you're calling `define('IN_PHPBB', true);` twice.  You cannot `define` a constant after it's been defined.

Comment: @sonia: It seems the problem is with the file loaded via `include`.  According to your current update, you can see the lines after the `include` in your page, so that means there is a problem in the `include` line.  Can you show us us the file being included?

Answer (score 2):

Short Version: It's not. PHP terminates at `?>` (or possibly `%>` if you're using asp style tags).

Long Version: Take a look through your document, try placing various echo statements around to ensure you're exiting where you think you are. Edit the file with a plain text viewer if you can, to make sure your editor isn't hiding anything from you.

**Update**
Ensure that your include is performing correctly. If it's unable to find that file, or the file doesn't create the `user` object, your next line will fail, and PHP will terminate.

Comment: And turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: It's `$user->session_begin();` so presumably that's part of the `$user` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's the spaces:

```
//replace
$user -> session_begin();

//with
$user->session_begin();
```

and all other places where `->` is a space.

Comment: I just tested this, and it's not actually the issue.  PHP doesn't care if there's white space around the `->` operator.

Comment: OK, where are you actually instantiating the `$user` object? I'm assuming you have this before the first `<?php` .

Comment: Or in the file being included.