# Why is PHP Object Operator being viewed as closing tag in browser?

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP to check for $_SESSION variables at the top of an HTML page. Here is my code:

```
<?php require('sessions.class.php');
 $session= new session();
 $session->start_session('_s',false);

 if (!isset($_SESSION('session_id'))){
    header(location:'login.html');
  }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Everything seems to work until the Object Operator (`->`) is reached. It's like the server views this as the PHP closing tag. The text after `->` is echoed at the top of the webpage.

This is similar to the question asked here:

[why-php-tag-is-closing-on-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894334/why-php-tag-is-closing-on-user)

But the OP did not go into the solution with much detail.

Browser= Mozilla

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not the browser who "views" that, PHP is server side, not interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code? write it by hand in your text editor? It might be an invisible character

Comment: @Cristy- just updated the post to correct it. Thanks

Comment: what is the file extension of the document? Might it be .html by accident

Comment: @RPM- I did write it by hand. My text editor is VIM and it too views the `->` as a closing tag.

Comment: It works for me... http://codepad.org/uLIPdmA2

Comment: @Pankrates- The extension is `.html`. Sorry, I am very new to PHP so this might be a stupid question: Can you not use PHP at the top of an `.html` file?

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894334/why-php-tag-is-closing-on-user

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. Being a PHP n00b, I assumed I could use PHP in an `.html` file which I now understand is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are trying to run PHP code in an html document which is not possible. The < of the PHP opening tag is recognised as the start of an html tag and therefore the code after the first > is output as text, since it is interpreted as the closing of the html tag.

If you want to use PHP, make it a .php file and echo the html. Better yet you want to separate your logic (PHPcode) and markup (html) in separate files as much as possible.

Search for 'separating PHP and html'
[To get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html)

Comment: Thanks Pankrates. I appreciate the explanation and link provided above.