# PHP object operator "->" being read as PHP end "?>"

Tags: php

I have this PHP written for editing records in SQL. I have an almost identical page for editing other records on another table that works just fine.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","----","----","mitchpol_gigs");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$adds['v_venue'] = $con->/*Text-Start*/real_escape_string($_POST['v_venue']);
$adds['v_url'] = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['v_url']);
$adds['v_address'] = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['v_address']);

$sql = "
UPDATE `venues` 
SET v_venue='". $adds['v_venue']. "', v_url='". $adds['v_url']. "', v_address='". $adds['v_address']. "'
WHERE v_id='$_POST[v_id]'";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Venue edited successfully.<br><br>
    Input summary:
    <br>Edited: ID" . $_POST['v_id'] . "
    <br>Venue: " . $_POST['v_venue'] . "
    <br>URL: " . $_POST['v_url'] . "
    <br>Address: " . $_POST['v_address'] . "
    <br><br>";
    } else {
        echo 'Error: '. $con->error . '<br>';
        }

include 'venueedit.php';
?>
```

Instead of executing the code the page returns with all the text from where I have noted in the code "Text-Start" to the end of the document.

This is the error that I get:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$con' (T_VARIABLE) in (path)insertvenuesedit.php on line 1

It's as if the "->" is recognized as the end of the code in place of "?>".

My file is definitely a .php and not .html.

I read to make sure short_open_tag is off in my php.ini file. It is.
I'm wondering if there is another php.ini variable that could cause this?

EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED but curious about solution.

Turns out it was an issue in my editor. I'm using notepad++. I copy and pasted my code from another page and made the few edits I needed to apply it to this situation. The code was displaying as I posted it above but after closing the file and re-openeing it displayed all my code on one line. After spacing everything appropriately the code works just fine.

In other words ?php $con=mysqli_connect was posting as php$con=mysqli_connect with no space between ?php and $con.

Anybody run into that kind of thing using notepad++?

Comment: Another common pitfall is to change the `short_open_tag` value in the wrong php.ini (i.e. the php.ini for the `cli`).

Comment: `$con->/*Text-Start*/real_escape_string($_POST['v_venue']);` what is `/*Text-Start*/`

Comment: Is there other code running before this code? For example when you include this file into another file. If so, it is possible you have a syntax error in that file, for example a missing ;. Because the error message refers to the first line in this code example.

Comment: Akam - When the page loads it shows me the text from that point to the end of the document. That note is not actually in my code.

Comment: Is it possible that venueedit.php is a contributor here as well? Please share its source, too, or try running your code with its include line commented out.

Comment: Jan-Henk, I posted my referring page above. I'm still looking to find any possible syntax issues.

Comment: Randall - Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Comment: This looks altogether like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297867/why-is-php-object-operator-being-viewed-as-closing-tag-in-browser. The answer there is that the file is not being interpreted as PHP - view the source to see if you're seeing the same (i.e. the entire file contents is being displayed, but the browser is interpreting everything up to that point as an HTML tag).

Comment: Have you tried changing your `$con` connection to an Object oriented style connection [`new mysqli()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) / `$con=new mysqli("localhost","----","----","mitchpol_gigs");`, instead of your Procedural style [`mysqli_connect()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) / `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","----","----","mitchpol_gigs");`

Comment: @cbuckley - I think you are on to something. Viewing the source shows all the code in one line. Yet my file is definitely a php file. Here is another interesting thing. There is no space between <?php and $con on the source: <?php$con=mysqli_connect. I wonder if that has anything to do with it and how would you fix that?

Comment: @cbuckley - That was the clue I needed although the solution wasn't what I expected. Seeing the code displayed on one line when viewing the source seemed odd to me so I closed my file and re-opened it and low and behold it was all on one line even though it was showing me something different. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP is not being parsed. That `->` operator happens to be the first greater-than sign after the start, so the browser sees an invalid HTML tag, followed by everything that comes after it. If you had chosen to View Source in the browser, you would see all the PHP there.

Comment: Thanks Kolink. Turns out it was a copy/paste issue with my editor.